# How to calculate total working hours in Python 3, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning python and using Pandas.
I'm stuck at how to calculate the working hours between two points of time (excluding holidays, ...)?
I have two columns

```
 Column A
 2018-05-11 16:59:00
 2018-05-11 16:59:00
2018-05-11 16:59:00
2018-05-11 16:59:00
2018-05-11 16:59:00
2018-05-11 16:59:00

Column B:
 2018-05-11 16:59:00
 2018-05-11 16:59:00
2018-05-11 16:59:00
2018-05-11 16:59:00
2018-05-11 16:59:00
2018-05-11 16:59:00
```

-
Column C is the content of Column B - Column A (after eliminating break-time)
I have used the module below but failed:
https://pypi.org/project/business-duration/

---

I want to count working hour only, so I found the module: 
https://pypi.org/project/business-duration/
I have tried single data by:

```
businessDuration(startdate=data['A'][0],enddate=data['B'][0],unit='hour')
```

That's works, but the below code does not work:

```
businessDuration(startdate=data['A'],enddate=data['B'],unit='hour')
```

Can you help me to explain?

Comment: Please check your data: `Column A` and `Column B` are exactly the same. Also, what is your expected output?

Comment: You've received a pretty good answer.  However, your question still lacks in quality.  I'd suggest using the data provided by @TroyD and update your post incorporating sacul's comments.  At that point, this would be a useful question.  If you do that, please leave a comment to me that you did so I can vote accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, assuming you meant these to be different times, you can just do normal addition and subtraction on datetimes:

```
data = [
['2018-05-11 16:50:00', '2018-05-11 16:59:00'],
['2018-05-11 16:45:00', '2018-05-11 16:59:00'],
['2018-05-11 16:19:00', '2018-05-11 16:59:00'],
        ]

data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B'])
data = data.apply(pd.to_datetime)
data['C'] = data['B'] - data['A']
print(data)
```

output:

```
                    A                   B        C
0 2018-05-11 16:50:00 2018-05-11 16:59:00 00:09:00
1 2018-05-11 16:45:00 2018-05-11 16:59:00 00:14:00
2 2018-05-11 16:19:00 2018-05-11 16:59:00 00:40:00
```

Comment: `data.apply(pd.to_datetime).assign(C=lambda d: d.B - d.A)`

Comment: Nice call piRSquared.  updated answer

Comment: Is the "assign" with a lambda any better or worse than just data['C'] = data.B - data.A? Assuming A and B are already datetimes?

Comment: To my knowledge, it's not any better or worse.  I thought it'd be better since allows for one line, but now that I look at it again the .assign may be less readable, so I'm switching that back.